# How to preload all .ts of m3u8 with video.js

Tags: video.js

I am using [`video.js`](https://docs.videojs.com/index.html) to play m3u8 links.
I found it would continuously download `.ts` segments during playing.

I would like to create a loading overlay for preparation period, and when all is done, it disappears and user can watch video just like local.

So, is it possible to preload all segments during the loading period before playing?

**Update**

I found the m3u8 file contains .ts links, is it possible to predownload those blobs and intercept `fetch` requests to return downloaded blobs as response?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:60
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-START-TIME:3516
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-02-19T14:55:59+08:00
#EXTINF:2.01,
2758527764_1103365203_1.ts?start=0&end=91931&type=mpegts&resolution=320x240
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-02-19T14:56:01+08:00
#EXTINF:1.979,
2758527764_1103365203_1.ts?start=91932&end=171643&type=mpegts&resolution=320x240
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-02-19T14:56:02+08:00
#EXTINF:1.932,
2758527764_1103365203_1.ts?start=171644&end=248159&type=mpegts&resolution=320x240
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-02-19T14:56:04+08:00
#EXTINF:2.002,
2758527764_1103365203_1.ts?start=248160&end=318659&type=mpegts&resolution=320x240
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-02-19T14:56:06+08:00
#EXTINF:2.064,
2758527764_1103365203_1.ts?start=318660&end=393295&type=mpegts&resolution=320x240
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that waht you would to do isn't the case of use of **adaptive streaming**, so you shouldn't use HLS or DASH.

Maybe you could achieve this type of experience using sample mp4 playback.

Comment: this is not decided by us, our vendor only gave us m3u8 links and we needed to play it in our site. if we would like to use mp4, we will have to convert it by ourselves and buy storage for converted video

Comment: Ok, I got your point. What about increase the buffer size with a high value?

Comment: I tried but it seemed not working as the video alway preloaded one `.ts` instead of more no matter how big the buffer is

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "videojs.Vhs.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH" value to a high figure. It's the number of seconds which will be pre-loaded. However there is a playback issue when too much is buffered. Reason is all these buffered segments ends up eating ram. On mid range mobile devices more than few minutes of pre-load make the video un-usable.

I use it with few thousand students who can pre-load larger chunk (10min), so they are not interrupted continuously when having a low bandwidth connection.